# Whether a file name is syntactically valid in Java?

Tags: java, file

How to find out in Java whether a file name in file system is syntactically valid? 
Method should be independent of the operation system.

Comment: Valid in what sense? Syntactically valid? Refers to an existing file? Can be created? Local filesystems only or also remote?

Comment: Whether s a file name is valid depends on the filesystem you are writing it to i.e. it depends on the path and the machine you are on.  There is no absolute check for this.

Comment: Syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

1. Check permission to write files
2. Use `File.createNewFile()`, the method returns `true` if file was created -> name is valid

Comment: Although that's not so helpful if you don't have permission to create new files, it is generally a smart way. Presumably you want to write it eventually after all

Comment: You might not have access to the directory or it might not exist.  Its not clear if this should be invalid or not. If the file fails to be created because it already exists, it is valid.

Comment: @MC Emperror, this mehod should works in different operation systems.

Comment: Use try catch or check permission, matter of taste